# vb.net refresh datagridview every 20 second

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, refresh

I want to ask how to refresh and update the datagridview data every 20 second.
What I want is when I adding the data into database, datagrdview will refresh and show the latest data that in database.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    dgvRecord.Refresh()
End Sub
```

I tried in this way but it's no work.
Database part is OK but i had problem at refresh datagridview part.
hope can help me solve the question ,thank you!

Comment: Did you start the timer?

Comment: If you add a bit more of your code you are more likely to get some interest otherwise everyone has to start like Chris above saying... Did you.....?